# Como deixar o json de duas ou mais classes objeto no mesmo nivel em Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, linq

Tenho 3 classes sendo elas Contato, Setor, Unidade assim tenho Contato com relacionamento de um para muitos com Setor e Unidade gerando o Json com muitas camadas, impossibilitando o JQuery Bootgrid de acessar estes campos.

Verificando documentação do JQuery Bootgrid percebi que ele não dá suporte ao **data-column-id="Unidade.Nome"**

**Classe Contato**

```
 public class Contato
{
    [Key]
    public int ContatoID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public int UnidadeID { get; set; }
    public Unidade Unidade { get; set; }

    public int SetorID { get; set; }
    public Setor Setor { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Unidade**

```
 public class Unidade
{
    [Key]
    public int UnidadeID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Classe Setor**

```
public class Setor
{
    [Key]
    public int SetorID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Estas classes estão gerando o seguinte JSON**

```
rows: [
{
ContatoID: 4,
Nome: "Luiz",
UnidadeID: 1,
          Unidade: {
                    UnidadeID: 1,
                    Nome: "Oeste Paulista Setor 1"
           },
}
```

**O return do Controller responsável em retornar o Json é este**

```
return Json(new {
   rows = contatosPaginados.ToList(),
   current = current,
   rowCount = rowCount,
   total = total
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

***A pergunta é como faço para que o Json venha tudo no mesmo nível?***

```
[{
  ContatoID: 4,
  Nome: "Luiz",
  Ramal: "9500",
  UnidadeID: 1,
  NomeUnidade: "Oeste Paulista Setor 1"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Criando um novo objeto com todas as propriedades dos objetos internos.

É possível criar um tipo anônimo ou criar uma classe pra representar este tipo.

Usando LINQ fica bem fácil.

```
var dados = contatosPaginados
                        .ToList()
                        .Select(c => new 
                               { 
                                   ContatoID = c.contatoID,
                                   Nome = c.Nome,
                                   UnidadeID = c.Unidade.UnidadeID,
                                   NomeUnidade = c.Unidade.Nome
                               }).ToList();

return Json(new { rows = dados, current = current, rowCount = rowCount, total = total }, 
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DaoContato {
    public int ContatoID {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
    public int Ramal {get;set;}
    public int UnidadeID {get;set;}
    public int NomeUnidade {get;set;}
 }

  List< DaoContato > lista =  TABELA.Select(x=> new DaoContato () { ContatoID = x.ContatoID, Nome = x.Nome .... }
```

Se precisar pode fazer um JOIN entre as tabelas utilizando o próprio entity framework.

E para retornar pode utilizar o

```
return Json( lista, AllowGet);
```